# css editor in php like wordpress's css editor

Tags: php, css, wordpress, editor

I want to make css manager for my site like wordpress's css manager.
I want to open css file in textarea so I can edit it than after pressing submit button, changes in css file should be saved.
Please help me. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn PHP's [filesystem functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) (fopen , fwrite etc. )

But if your question is emergency , basically you can get a file's content with :

```
file_get_contents("file.css");
```

and then you can put new content to file with :

```
file_put_contents("file.css");
```